# Notification after Form Submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have a form that feeds fields into a website. But i would like to send a separate email, once my form has been submitted, to notify the client that a lead has been submitted.

This form collects customer information and is fed to a website where all the client information is stored. That part of the form works perfectly. I need to create a separate action, or a trigger, that sends a notification to an email, alerting my client that the application has been filled. Everything that I have tried either submits the form without sending an email, or sends an email without submitting the information. I have changed information in the code for my clients confidentiality.

```
<form action="This is the domain that submits to the website but for client confidentiality i cannot display" method="POST" >

<input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D1U000001ANuJ">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="/pages/wholesale-application-thank-you">


      <label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" class="input-full" placeholder="First Name"/><br>

      <label for="last_name" >Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" class="input-full" placeholder="Last Name"/><br>

      <label for="title" >Title</label><input  id="title" maxlength="40" name="title" size="20" type="text" class="input-full" placeholder="Title"/><br>

      <label for="company" >Company</label><input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" class="input-full" placeholder="Company"/><br>

      <label for="URL" >Website</label><input  id="URL" maxlength="80" name="URL" size="20" type="text" class="input-full" placeholder="Website"/><br>

      <label for="email" >Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" class="input-full" placeholder="Email"/><br>

      <label for="street" >Street</label><textarea name="street" class="input-full" placeholder="Street"></textarea><br>

      <label for="city" >City</label><input  id="city" maxlength="40" name="city" size="20" type="text" class="input-full" placeholder="City"/><br>

      <label for="zip" >Zip</label><input  id="zip" maxlength="20" name="zip" size="20" type="text" class="input-full" placeholder="Zip"/><br>

     <label for="state" >State/Province</label><input  id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" class="input-full" placeholder="State/Province"/><br>

     <label for="lead_source" >Lead Source</label><select  id="lead_source" name="lead_source" class="input-full"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="Events">Events</option>
     <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
     <option value="Google">Google</option>
     <option value="Instagram">Instagram</option>
     <option value="Retailer">Retailer</option>
     <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
     <option value="Third Party Site">Third Party Site</option>
     <option value="Trade Publication">Trade Publication</option>
     <option value="Trade Shows">Trade Shows</option>
     <option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
     <option value="YouTube">YouTube</option>
     </select><br>


     <input type="submit" name="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: Show us the part that actually does the work... whether you submit via ajax or the old fashioned way, it's still the server side where the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a `submit` event listener to the form? Something along these lines:

```
document.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.id === 'form-id') { // you'll need to give your form an id
        // do something like send an email
    };
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I dont know if i executed this correctly.

Comment: ` document.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.id === 'form-id') {
    $.post(ajaxurl, {});
    };
};
     
 <?php

$message = "A new wholesale lead has been created";
$message .= print_r($_POST, true);


$to = "ruben@vanquishgroupco.com";
$subject = "New Wholesale Lead";
$headers = "From: Wholesale";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 




?>`

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I can't be much help with PHP